# Looping of Mediaplayer not working in BroadCast Reciever

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to play a sound when my broadcast reciever's on recieve gets the call.
I am able to play the sound through MediaPlayer but the loop doesn't work.
I am guessing that the broadcast reciever gets destroyed after some time thats why my MediaPlayer gets destroyed and doesn't play.

Does any one know how can I loop my MediaPlayer in BroadcastReciever

Here is my code

```
    public class MyReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    MediaPlayer mp = null;
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {   
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.siren);/
                mp.setLooping(true);
                mp.start();// a

            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the extra parenthesis